# How to connect a home to the government electrical network

Tags: cables, electricity

I want to connect my home to the government electrical network, I used twisted cable, my home is 200m meters from the nearest electric pole. How do I calculate the twisted cable section?

Comment: You're going to kill yourself. Please don't do this.

Comment: Why isn't your home already connected?  What you are doing seems illegal so don't expect us to help.

Comment: what is `government electrical network`?

Comment: Don't worry, maybe I made mistakes in formulating the question. I do not really want to connect my house to electricity. I am studying as a technician in electricity and I want to learn how to do a comprehensive study of a project to connect a house with electricity from the government electrical network.

Comment: @ jsotola, like EDF in france (Electricité De France).

Comment: "*I am studying as a technician in electricity ...*" Wait until you are instructed properly.